# Afterv upgrade of 11.10 to 12.04 my laserjet 5P did not work

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, printing

tried $sudo modprobe usblp that helped for the 11.04 version but does not work here. Hardware is 64 bit,i3 cpu530@2.9 GHzx4,message is printer not connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried updating the packages since the upgrade to 12.04?

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in a terminal